# Здравствуйте, как передать 2 параметра по гет запросу через ссылку

Tags: php, laravel

шаблон

```
@foreach($closes as $close)

 <a href="{{ route('subcategories', $closes->name, $closes->nameTable) }}" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><h5><b>{{$close->name}}</b></h5></a>

 @endforeach
```

роут

```
Route::get('{name}/{nameTable}', 'HomeController@subcategories')->name('subcategories');
```

контролер

```
public function subcategories($name, $nameTable){

            $data['cheese'] = $nameTable;
            $closes = DB::table('closes')->where('name', '=', $name)->get();
            return view('pages.categories', ['closes'=>$closes], $data);
        }
```

---

```
$closes->name, $closes->nameTable
```

не выводит nameTable в url

```
$closes->name->nameTable
```

пишет вот эту ошибку:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Так вы же пытаетесь метод взять с коллекции, а не с элемента коллекции, в `foreach` посмотрите внимательно, нужно использовать переменную `close` вместо `closes`:

```
@foreach($closes as $close)

 <a href="{{ route('subcategories', $close->name, $close->nameTable) }}" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><h5><b>{{$close->name}}</b></h5></a>

 @endforeach
```